# How can I modify the interfaces of multiple blueprints at once?

Tags: interface, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I modified one interface, but dozens of blueprints have tried it, can I change it with a script or tool in one click?

Ok, I have checked the document of `Core Redirects`, and it seems to be doing something like temporarily modifying the mapping of variables, functions, classes, etc. in the blueprint, but since there is always a configuration file, it is not quite what I expected.

Comment: It sounds like you might be after [core redirects](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/Assets/CoreRedirects/).

Comment: Thank you! That sounds very similar to my needs. I'll learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well...
You could create one parental blueprint and make a bunch of other blueprints that are inherited from it. Then all the changes you do to the parent will be applied to its children.

Comment: If function calls between blueprints can't do that. George gave me a tip. I'll try core redirects.